# How to use AngularUI Dialog for lightbox

Tags: angular-ui

I have a partial page that shows a list of files on the server. I want to allow the user to choose a file and display it in a lightbox dialog using AngularUI. I can't figure out how to get the filename that should be displayed into the dialog template correctly. Here's my file list html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in files | orderBy:orderProp">
   <td><a href='#' ng-click="openInLightbox(file.linkURL)">{{file.name}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

And here's the applicable part of that view's controller:

```
function FileListCtrl($scope, $http, $dialog) 
{

  .
  .
  .

  $scope.openInLightbox = function(item){
      var d = $dialog.dialog({
                              modalFade: false, 
                              resolve: {item: function(){ return angular.copy(item); } }});
      d.open('dialogs/lightboxTemplate.html', 'LightboxController');
   }
}
```

and here's the lightboxController:

```
app.controller('LightboxController', ['$scope', 'dialog', 'item', function($scope, dialog, item){
    $scope.item = item;
    console.log("item:" + item);
    $scope.submit = function(){
        dialog.close('ok');
    };
}]);
```

and here's my dialog template:

```
<img src={{item}} />
```

I have two things I don't understand:

1) I get a lightbox on the first image I choose correctly, but the console gives a 404 error getting "(URL path to image)/{{item}}". So I get an error, but the image still appears.

2) When I click outside the lightbox, it disappears and I can't reload a new image. I think this is due to having no close button?

Am I properly binding the "item" scope property into the dialog template? If not, what is the correct way?

Comment: To somewhat answer my own question. The major problem was that the end  characters of the img tag on the template were '/>' rather than simply '>'. This fixed things. However, it still tries getting the image using the {{item}} literal and can't find it (the 404 error). Perhaps that's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-src for example:

```
<img ng-src="{{item}}>
```

It will likely overcome the weirdness as /> is still valid html (just not html 5)